# Applescript: Keeping track of multiple terminal windows and writing into each of them

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, applescript, buffer

I've got a setup procedure for a project that involves me using multiple terminal windows. The start up procedure is sort of messy and involves me tabbing between the terminal windows (different tools running) and sequentially inputting commands into each terminal.

Applescript is useful for getting the first run of commands out and opening all my terminals with the:

```
do script "echo blablablabla"
```

These are decent because they open new terminal windows each time I "do script". This is actually more beneficial to me than tabbing (although, I couldn't quite figure out tabbing between terminal tabs).

However, I'd like to keep track of these windows since I need to go back to specific ones and input more commands. Any ideas?

More specifically: 
Is there a way I can add an alias for each window to track it and tab back to it in the Applescript? If so, how do I implement it?

Answer (score 2):

`do script` has an `in` specifier:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    set t to do script "echo a"
    do script "echo b"
    do script "echo c" in t
    set index of window 2 to 1
end tell
```

Or using tabs:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    set t to do script "echo a"
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke "t" using command down
    do script "echo b" in window 1
    set selected tab of window 1 to t
end tell
```

Comment: Trying it out atm. Will upvote and accept answer once I verify! Thanks!